# Shared minitest tests in modules which use classes to describe context

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a minitest controller test set up as so:

```
module Api::V1
  module Foos
    class FoosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

      class IndexTest < self

        class NotLoggedInTest < self

          test 'it denies access' do
            perform_request
            assert_response :unauthorized
          end
        end

        class AdminLoggedInTest < self

          def perform_request
            sign_in admin_user
            super
          end

          test 'it allows admins access' do
            perform_request
            assert_response :success
          end
        end

        def perform_request
          get :index, format: :json
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

It uses nested classes (e.g. `IndexTest`) to separate different contexts of the test while still allowing to share some functionality.

Now I need this exact test for another controller so I'm attempting to create a module that when included will dynamically define the different test classes and allow them to inherit from the including class.

For example (this doesn't work):

```
module Support
  module SharedControllerTest
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do |base|
      base.const_set 'IndexTest', Class.new(base) do

            # For example
            test 'it works' do
              assert_nil nil
            end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

This fails with a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'setup' for #<Class:0x00000004821fc8>`.

How would I go about creating a module which when included can dynamically define my different test classes and set them to inherit from the including class?

**Edit 1:**

I'm attempting to include this module in the controller as so:

```
module Api::V1
  module Foos
    class FoosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      include Support::SharedControllerTest
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show how you are including/extending this module?

Comment: @maxpleaner - updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
module Support
  module SharedControllerTest
    def self.included(base)
      base.const_set "IndexTest", Class.new(base) {
        test 'it works' do
          assert_nil nil
        end
      }
    end
  end
end


module Api::V1
  module Foos
    class FoosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      include Support::SharedControllerTest
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if you need any help or have any questions.